# Diplomacy - failed attack

Tags: diplomacy

Right now I'm the game master and we discuss the following scenario:

- Greece is empty
- all troops move at the same time
- Austrian fleet:  Ionian Sea - Greece
- Osmanian fleet: Aegean Sea - Greece
- Italian fleet: East Mediterranean - Aegean Sea

So the result is that Greece stays empty but what happens to the Aegean Sea? 
In my opinion the Osmanian fleet gets defeated in Greece and comes back to the Aegean Sea but there is the Italian fleet waiting.

Answer (score 12):

We have

Austria
  F Ion-Gre

Turkey
  F Aeg-Gre

Italy
  F EMa-Aeg

F Ion-Gre bounces with F Aeg-Gre because both have strength 1 so nobody wins.   As a result the fleets never leave their spaces and thus F Aeg stays at Aeg.

So F EMa-Aeg attacks an occupied space. Both have strength 1 so both stay at their spaces with the end result that nothing changes.

Answer (score 3):

All units move at the same time, but units only leave their current location if their move is successful. In this case, F Aeg - Gre bounces, therefore there is still a fleet in Aegean Sea, therefore the Italian fleet trying to move into Aegean Sea would require at least 1 offensive support.

Note that units who are moving away cannot be supported defensively, but theoretically someone else could try to enter the same space (e.g. F Con S Smy - Aeg), thereby blocking a supported attack (e.g. F Ion S Eme - Aeg).

When in doubt, try using an open source adjudicator such as Realpolitik: http://realpolitik.sourceforge.net/